# Understanding the Promise Constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Here's a code snippet from MDN Promise [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // We call resolve(...) when what we were doing asynchronously was successful, and reject(...) when it failed.
  // In this example, we use setTimeout(...) to simulate async code. 
  // In reality, you will probably be using something like XHR or an HTML5 API.
  setTimeout( function() {
    resolve("Success!")  // Yay! Everything went well!
  }, 250) 
})
```

In above code, I don't understand where is the function definition of `resolve` (and `reject`)? Here we are simply passing `resolve` as a parameter to the `Promise` constructor, and later calling it when we do `resolve("Success!")`, so where exactly is `resolve` defined?

Comment: You aren't *passing* that parameter, just *naming* it; you're passing an *arrow function*. I'd recommend reading up on higher-order and callback functions, they're used a lot in JS.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Your highest active tag is JavaScript - have you not encountered callbacks before? It's very common in JS - you define a function that *will be called* with other functions (or any values) as arguments. For example `[1, 2, 3].map((item) => item * 2)` the function *will be called with* an argument named `item` but *you* never pass it in, it's done for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple parts to this, first this is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so:

```
(resolve, reject) => {}
```

is short-hand for (and some other stuff around `this`, etc):

```
function(resolve, reject){}
```

So you're passing a function as a parameter into the other function. Functions are [objects in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions). So if you imagine the implementation of `Promise` it **might** look something like this (not the actual implementation):

```
Promise(callBackFunction){
    ...//do some things
    callBackFunction(resolve, reject); 
}
```

So, `callBackFunction` is the function you have passed in using the arrow function and when promise gets to the relevant point in the code, it will call your function and pass it `resolve, reject`. `resolve` and `reject` are also function objects here.

> so where exactly is resolve defined

Inside the `Promise` code.

Comment: So you are basically saying that the `Promise` constructor passes the reference of a function (which it internally might have named as 'resolve' or something similar) to this first parameter of our passed function, called `resolve`?

Comment: @maverick - it's just like any other callback function ... *which it internally might have named* - doesn't need an "internal" name at all

Comment: Yes this ^ this pattern pre-dates promises and arrow functions

Comment: Looking at the two answers Maverick has made, he knows what an arrow function is :p

Comment: @JaromandaX haha, yes I do know what an arrow function is! Even callbacks! But just got a bit confused here, and I like to understand things in detail rather than glancing over stuff under assumptions.